# I need to change an img element's src using ${} with an entry but it doesn't recognize the ${} sign as an directory

Tags: javascript

This is normal text : I need to change an image element's source using ${} with an entry but it doesn't recognize the $ sign as an directory.so it doesn't load any picture because it simply doesn't find a picture with name of "dice-${dicee}.jpg"
here is the code:

```
document.getElementsByClassName('btn--roll')[0].addEventListener('click',()=>{
const dicee = Math.trunc(Math.random()*6)+1;
diceElement.classList.remove('hidden');
diceElement.src = 'images/dice-${dicee}.jpg';
})
```

Comment: Need to use backticks instead of normal quotes. `\`${x}\``.

Comment: You're looking for [Template Literals](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals).

Answer (score 1):

Interporlation only works inside template literals
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Template_literals